# Can a Gluon Mobile project automatically download and include libCharm.a?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I have written a small sample that makes use of `com.gluonhq.charm.down.common.ScanService`. It works as expected on a real iOS device, **if** I manually include the native library libCharm.a in src/ios/jniLibs. This is explained in the Gluon documentation of their [GoNative](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/) app. If I am not mistaken, the library is built in the build.gradle file of Charm Down IOS.

Here is the build.gradle of my sample. As I have said, this leads to a fully working app if I copy libCharm.a manually to src/ios/jniLibs.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.thomaskuenneth.scanservicedemo.ScanserviceDemo'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:3.0.0'

    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:3.0.0'
    androidRuntime 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:3.0.0'

    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {

    apply plugin: 'idea'
    idea.module.downloadJavadoc = true

    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'

        androidSdk = '/Users/thomas/Library/Android/sdk'
        compileSdkVersion = 23
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.google.zxing.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'io.datafx.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to add a iosRuntime dependency to the latest version of charm-down-ios, but this seemed to have no effect. So, the question: is there a way to automatically get a libCharm.a that matches my specified dependencies or is the manual way (which, again, does work) the only one possible? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no automatic tool for this included in the plugin that manages the proper installation of the native library, extracting it from the charm-down-ios.jar and moving it to the `jniLibs` library of the project. But it should be available in a future version of the plugin.

For now, you have to do it manually, as you mentioned, extracting the `libCharm.a` file from the `charm-ios-3.0.0.jar` that will be located on your local .m2 repository, and copying it into your project under `src/ios/jniLibs`.

I've come up with this task that will help you do it:

```
task extractNativeLib(type: Sync) {
    def iosNativeDir = project.file(project.jfxmobile.ios.nativeDirectory)
    if (!iosNativeDir.exists()) {
        iosNativeDir.mkdirs()
    } 

    setIncludeEmptyDirs(false)
    from {
        configurations.iosRuntime.collect { zipTree(it).matching { include 'native/**' } }
    }
    into iosNativeDir
    eachFile {details -> details.path = details.name }
}
```

Run this task before calling `launchIOSDevice`, and it will extract the library and copy it into your native folder.

**EDIT**

Since the release of the javafxmobile plugin 1.1.0 (October 2016) there is no need for using this task, as the plugin will manage it.

For the Charm Down 3.0.0+ plugins included in the project, their native libraries will be automatically added to the build, as well as any other third party native library included in `src/ios/jniLibs`.

Comment: Awesome. As always, José, you answer is very much appreciated. Thanks a lot for your great support.